# Dropdown menu in React not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a simple dropdown menu in a card element but am having issues getting the menu to actually show up. I inspected it on Chrome and it says the menu is there but I can't get it to show up on the screen.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: true,
        open: false
    };
}

    toggleDropDown = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
};

<div className="content">
     <div
         onClick={event => {
             event.stopPropagation();
         }}
         onFocus={() => {
             this.toggleDropDown();
         }}
         onBlur={() => {
             this.toggleDropDown();
         }}
         tabIndex="0"
         className="ui right floated dropdown" >
         <i className="ellipsis vertical icon" />
              {this.state.open ? (
                    <div className="menu">
                         <div className="item">
                              <i className="edit icon" /> Edit Post
                         </div>
                         <div className="item">
                              <i className="delete icon" />Remove Post
                         </div>
                         <div className="item">
                              <i className="hide icon" /> Hide Post
                         </div>
                    </div>
              ) : null}
        </div>
        <div className="header">{schedule.title}</div>
        <div className="description">
              <p>{schedule.description}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="meta">
             <span className="right floated time">
                   {moment(schedule.date).fromNow()}
             </span>
       </div>
 </div>
```

This is a screenshot of the card I am producing (div with classname content is all that shows up in the picture).
[Reactjs dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H579M.png)

Comment: Where is your `render()` method?

Comment: I cut off a lot of the code since it's pretty long. It renders correctly. This is the git link if you want to see https://github.com/littlejkim/Sked/blob/master/client/src/components/Dashboard.js

Comment: Better than nothing, but I'd rather see something I can actually test. Can you throw something together on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: What happens when you comment out the `this.toggleDropDown();` in your `onBlur` callback?

Comment: It's the same. I'm going to try with the sandbox but I don't think it's a problem with the react part since the html elements work correctly (div of classname menu appears when I press it and disappears when I lose focus). It's just that the elements themselves don't actually appear on the screen which is weird.

Comment: If you can get things on screen I'll probably be able to help you.

Comment: This is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/9yvv5lnzy4?fontsize=14

Comment: I updated my answer with a fix. Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `.menu`, although it is appearing in the inspector, is set to `display: none`.

Here's me disabling the property.

[image]

And here's the menu displaying as expected:

[image]

Here's a crude fix showing that it's a `display` issue: [CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qv1kzzq5q6).

Comment: Last question. I'm mapping through an array to create several card elements on the screen. Right now, I have a ternary operator for each card to either display or not display the menu; but my current implementation (which shows either all the menus of all the cards or none) isn't optimal. Do you have a suggestion on how to do this efficiently? Would I have to pass the id of the card through the toggle function?

Comment: @YoungDoKim Off to bed, but will have a look tomorrow.

Comment: @YoungDoKim Each card should be its own component and which has an `open` entry in `state`. Then, you show/hide cards if, say, an `active` class exists in the `className` of each `.menu`.

Answer (score 1):

We need to overwrite one css class forcefully like this:

```
.ui.dropdown .visible.menu {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```